# axios post request and JQuery $.ajax request both are return 403 forbidden error on mobile device

Tags: jquery, ajax, vuejs2, axios

I am working on an application using Vue and I am using axios for HTTP rest-api calls.

Find below the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vue Axios Example</title>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <h1>App</h1>
  <p>From Axios: {{response}}</p>      
</div>

<script src="vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {        
          users: [],
          response : ""
      }, 
      methods:{
        init:function() {
          var vm = this;
          axios(
              { 
                method : "POST", 
                "url" : "http://localhost:3000/", 
                "data" : myJSONText, 
                "headers" : 
                { 
                  "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8;" 
                }
              }
          )
          .then(function (result) {          
              //alert(result.data);
              stringData = result.data;
              vm.response = JSON.stringify(result.data);
              //$('.dataP').text(JSON.stringify(stringData));
          })
          .catch(function (error) {        
            alert(error);
          })
          .then(function () {

          });
        }
      }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working fine in the web browser.

Find the screenshot below.

[image]

But it is not working on the mobile device (Lenovo A6600 - android 4.4.2) got the 403 - forbidden error.

Please find the below mobile screenshot

[image]

For the further checking, I am using JQuery $.ajax post request too.

Below is the Jquery ajax code

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:3000/",          
   data: myJSONText,              
   contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",        
   dataType:"json",
   success: function( data ) {          
   stringData = data;
   console.log(stringData);
   $('.dataP').append(JSON.stringify(stringData));
   },
   error: function( error ) {
   console.log( error );
   alert("jq: "+JSON.stringify(error));          
   }
})
```

but this also returns the same 403 error.

Instead of localhost, I tried with my IP/Hostname and connecting the devices in the same network. That also gives the same error.

Any solutions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is `localhost:3000`. If this JS gets loaded in your mobile browser it is also going to try to connect to localhost (which is the phone now), where your server is obviously not running.
Change it to your actual server IP/Hostname and you should be fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I already tried with that too. Putting my IP/Hostname also giving the same error.

Comment: Are you sure your server running on your computer:3000 is accepting incoming request from external IPs and not just from localhost?

Comment: Yes.. My system accepting requests from both external and localhost. For your further information. I opened the same localhost link from my mobile's chrome browser and i got the response. Where as once i convert that into .apk package using cordova it is not working...